# R Code in QGIS - Stratified Random Sampling of Land Cover Classified Raster

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to write code using the Processing R Provider scripting in QGIS. The script is to perform a stratified random sampling scheme on a classified land cover raster image. The land cover codes are 1 (urban), 2 (agriculture), and 3 (water).

The code that I use in R is:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
landclass <- raster("Land8_sup_class_min_mc.tif")
names(landclass) <- 'stratum'
stratrand <- sampleStratified(landclass, size=10, xp=TRUE, sp=TRUE)
writeOGR(stratrand, dsn = ".", layer = "stratrand", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

The issue I am having is converting this R code to a syntax that can be used in QGIS. This is one of the many iterations I have tried thus far:

```
##XRaster = raster
##Size=number 10
##stratrand = output vector
library(sp)
library(raster)
R = raster(XRaster)
values(R) <- 1:ncell(R)
pts = sampleStratified(R, Size, xp=TRUE, sp=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(FID=row.names(pts), row.names=row.names(pts))
pts2 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, data=df)
stratrand = pts2
```

I get an error if I run the "names(landclass) <- 'stratum'" portion of the code from R and the values(R) portion of the code runs forever. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution:

```
##landclass=raster
##Size=number 10
##stratrand=output vector
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

names(landclass[[1]]) <- "stratum"
stratrand <- sampleStratified(landclass[[1]],
                              size = Size,
                              xp = TRUE,
                              sp = TRUE)
stratrand
```

Explanation: QGIS reads any raster as a RasterBrick. If you do `raster()` on a RasterBrick, you lose the values. Indexing by 1 (`[[1]]`) takes the first (and the only) layer from a RasterBrick and creates a RasterLayer.

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you for the assistance!